# Disable mouse middle button click paste on KDE, keeping that button working

Tags: mouse, clipboard, paste

How to disable mouse middle button click paste (AKA PRIMARY selection buffer), but keep that button working?

My system: Ubuntu 16.04 with KDE v5.8.5.

Comment: see  [Disabling middle mouse button](https://askubuntu.com/a/597071/723193). Your question currently looks to be a duplicate of this question. If there is a significant difference please clarify your question.

Comment: Related posts: [How do I disable middle mouse button click paste?](https://askubuntu.com/q/4507/37165), [Any updates on disabling middle-click paste?](https://askubuntu.com/q/349503/37165) have answers covering different solutions.

Comment: Please post an update and whether you were able to solve this. If applicable, post an answer and accept it.

Comment: Did you tried [this](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=142391)? More info [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Clipboard#Selections). If this question doesn't ask specifically for KDE seems a duplicate of [this one](https://askubuntu.com/q/4507/349837) mentioned by @clearkimura.

Comment: There is are answers for the same question here : https://askubuntu.com/questions/4507/how-do-i-disable-middle-mouse-button-click-paste

Answer (score 0):

You can install Klipper and turn on settings "ignore mouse selection".

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1190409)